# How do I remove the nested loop from this multiple join query in postgresql 10.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a table called sources with prices in it, I have another table called destinations with another set of values in it. I need to get all destinations for each source and therefore doing a cross join that multiplies each value from the sources table with each value from the destinations table
source_id and destination_id are primary keys and I want to inner join this resultant table with another table which currently gives me a nested loop

**APPROACH 1**

```
//has a nested loop
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM 
(select concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) AS pair_id, 
(s.price * d.price) AS pair_price 
FROM e1_sources s 
CROSS JOIN e1_destinations d) AS p
INNER JOIN e1_alerts a
ON a.pair=p.pair_id
WHERE 
(p.pair_price > a.value AND a.direction=true) OR
(p.pair_price <= a.value AND a.direction=false)
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
//has a nested loop
EXPLAIN WITH pairs AS 
(
    SELECT 
    concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) AS pair_id,
    (s.price * d.price) AS pair_price
    FROM e1_sources s
    CROSS JOIN e1_destinations d
)
SELECT * from pairs p
INNER JOIN e1_alerts a
ON p.pair_id=a.pair
WHERE 
(p.pair_price > a.value AND a.direction=true) OR 
(p.pair_price <= a.value AND a.direction=false)
```

**APPROACH 1 ANALYZE**

```
"Hash Join  (cost=3697.72..210978.26 rows=1297875 width=114)"
"  Hash Cond: (concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) = (a.pair)::text)"
"  Join Filter: ((((s.price * d.price) > a.value) AND a.direction) OR (((s.price * d.price) <= a.value) AND (NOT a.direction)))"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..19303.43 rows=1540440 width=70)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on e1_sources s  (cost=0.00..25.56 rows=1556 width=16)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..24.85 rows=990 width=54)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on e1_destinations d  (cost=0.00..19.90 rows=990 width=54)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=2025.00..2025.00 rows=75098 width=50)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on e1_alerts a  (cost=0.00..2025.00 rows=75098 width=50)"
"              Filter: (direction OR (NOT direction))"
```

**ARPPOACH 2 ANALYZE**

```
"Hash Join  (cost=56349.38..649740.92 rows=7089424 width=114)"
"  Hash Cond: (p.pair_id = (a.pair)::text)"
"  Join Filter: (((p.pair_price > a.value) AND a.direction) OR ((p.pair_price <= a.value) AND (NOT a.direction)))"
"  CTE pairs"
"    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..19378.74 rows=1104760 width=64)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on e1_sources s  (cost=0.00..26.56 rows=1556 width=16)"
"          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..20.65 rows=710 width=54)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on e1_destinations d  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=54)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on pairs p  (cost=0.00..22095.20 rows=1104760 width=64)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=20248.06..20248.06 rows=751007 width=50)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on e1_alerts a  (cost=0.00..20248.06 rows=751007 width=50)"
"              Filter: (direction OR (NOT direction))"
```

If however I were to have a separate table that contains the cross join product as pair_id and then If I did an inner join, I simple get a hash scan in the analyze and the query barely takes milliseconds

**APPROACH 3**
I have a materialized view called pairs which contains the cross join of sources and destinations with their concatenated pair_id as the primary key
Now an inner join takes merely seconds as it does not do a nested loop

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * from pairs p 
INNER JOIN e1_alerts a
ON p.pair_id = a.pair 
WHERE 
(p.pair_price > a.value AND a.direction=true) OR
(p.pair_price <= a.value AND a.direction=false)
```

**ANALYZE APPROACH 3**

```
"Hash Join  (cost=1459.32..4892.41 rows=30566 width=73) (actual time=14.048..92.158 rows=498 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((a.pair)::text = p.pair_id)"
"  Join Filter: (((p.pair_price > a.value) AND a.direction) OR ((p.pair_price <= a.value) AND (NOT a.direction)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 99502"
"  ->  Seq Scan on e1_alerts a  (cost=0.00..2025.00 rows=75098 width=50) (actual time=0.010..16.658 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (direction OR (NOT direction))"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=836.92..836.92 rows=49792 width=23) (actual time=13.736..13.736 rows=49792 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3245kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on pairs p  (cost=0.00..836.92 rows=49792 width=23) (actual time=0.005..5.029 rows=49792 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 0.494 ms"
"Execution time: 92.262 ms"
```

A few questions

1. Are approaches 1 and 2 doing nested join because they dont know if pair_id is a primary key, is there any way I can tell postgresql that a particular column arising out of the cross join is unique?
2. Is there no other way other than using a materialized view? My sources x destinations tables will contain 80000 values at worst which need to be updated every x minutes and I dont want to send so many updates to the database. If I were to send only sources and destinations which is approx 2000 values i would be able to generate the pairs table from a cross join

Comment: Note: most people don't like horizontal scrolling. (and I doubt if you *really* need the subquery)

Comment: @wildplasser this is the part "select concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) as pair_id" due to which I added a subquery, if you know a better method to do this, super helpful if you can share, thanks

Comment: It looks like you use concat() to emulate a composite (primary) key `concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) as pair_id,` . Why?

Comment: the string "XYZ:ABC" is roughly what the concatenated column looks like and I have a column like this inside e1_alerts with whom I want to perform an inner join

Comment: Why doesn't `e1_alerts` have a composite key (or index)

Comment: I tried having all combinations of keys but none of them are used as indexes get used only when the number of rows are below a certain percentage otherwise the query optimizer seems to do a sequential scan

Answer (score 1):

Allright, I found a solution that works 100x faster than anything I tried above but I have no idea why. When I did a cross join between 2 columns in my approach 1 and approach 2, I did not have any common column between the 2 tables. In order to convert this cross join into an inner join, I merely added the same column in both tables with the same repeating data and used this column as an excuse to perform an INNER JOIN but now the results are drastically different in terms of performance!!!

**APPROACH 4**

```
explain analyze SELECT * 
FROM 
(select concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) as pair_id, 
(s.price * d.price) as pair_price 
FROM e1_sources s 
INNER JOIN e1_destinations d 
ON s.destination_id=d.source_id) as p
INNER JOIN e1_alerts a
ON a.pair=p.pair_id
WHERE 
(p.pair_price > a.value AND a.direction=true) OR
(p.pair_price <= a.value AND a.direction=false)
```

Is this a way to fool the query optimizer to believe that it is doing an inner join. The same number of rows joined with an excuse of an inner join has completely eliminated the NESTED LOOP! I would appreciate if someone can shed light on why this is happening

**ANALYZE APPROACH 4**

```
"Hash Join  (cost=456.66..712.93 rows=1862 width=114) (actual time=4.702..67.509 rows=51 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (concat(s.source_id, ':', d.destination_id) = (a.pair)::text)"
"  Join Filter: ((((s.price * d.price) > a.value) AND a.direction) OR (((s.price * d.price) <= a.value) AND (NOT a.direction)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 9949"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=159.78..246.19 rows=5524 width=70) (actual time=0.630..13.783 rows=49792 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: ((d.source_id)::text = (s.destination_id)::text)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=50.72..52.50 rows=710 width=86) (actual time=0.042..0.049 rows=32 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: d.source_id"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on e1_destinations d  (cost=0.00..17.10 rows=710 width=86) (actual time=0.020..0.025 rows=32 loops=1)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=109.06..112.95 rows=1556 width=20) (actual time=0.583..4.144 rows=49761 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: s.destination_id"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 167kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on e1_sources s  (cost=0.00..26.56 rows=1556 width=20) (actual time=0.010..0.268 rows=1556 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=203.00..203.00 rows=7510 width=50) (actual time=3.507..3.507 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 16384 (originally 8192)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 949kB"
"        ->  Seq Scan on e1_alerts a  (cost=0.00..203.00 rows=7510 width=50) (actual time=0.013..1.771 rows=10000 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (direction OR (NOT direction))"
"Planning time: 0.251 ms"
"Execution time: 67.590 ms"
```

Comment: You are fooling the optimizer in such a way that it has to resort to sort/merge+hashjoin.  This might work for smaller result sets, but will become terrible once you outgrow (work_)mem. In real life you *really* should use (multiple,conditional)  composite indexes on your junction table  `e1_alerts`, instead of the carthesian product+join . And:  to me, `e1_alerts` s two  key columns seem to be correlated.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I have a doubt, when every value in e1_alerts for pair_price is going to be different in 99% cases, why would it use an index, also the value of pair_id at the worst case can have 50000 different values whereas at the best case can have only 1 value, given i have to check the where condition on all rows for e1_alerts, i think the query runner will skip indexes any way, what do you think? i tried composite indexes but the query planner was not using any of them, tried all combinations of them

Comment: You should match on indexed keys, not on the values. Once the corresponding record is found, comparing the `value <--> value*value`  is almost for free.

Comment: ... and you don't even have to match the values for the not-found keys!